# PHP Custom Error Handler won't run SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP custom error handler that does everything it's supposed to besides run a DB query. The code is below

```
public function fatalErrHandlr(){
    $errstrArr = error_get_last();
    $errno = $errstrArr['type'];
    $errstr = $errstrArr['message'];
    $errfile = $errstrArr['file'];
    $errline = $errstrArr['line'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `err` (`errno`, `errstr`, `errfile`, `errline`) VALUES ('$errno', '$errstr', '$errfile', '$errline')";
    mysqli_query($this->dbc, $query);
    echo("<b>There was an error. Check the database.</b>");
    return true;
}
```

When I run this, it should put the error in the database, but nothing is added to the table. I did run the query in phpMyAdmin, and there are no errors there.

Comment: Try printing your query and see how it's formed. That will give you an idea if anything is wrong.

Comment: I would start debugging by detaching your custom error handler again and feeding the errstrArr-array with data, then running the code you wrote here seperately to see if it actually throws errors.

Comment: `var_dump(mysqli_error($this->dbc));` to see errors

Comment: @CodeGodie Thank you, this made me figure out the answer. Check out what I posted below.

Comment: No problem, any time. Im glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was lack of `mysqli_real_escape_string();`, it was simply something I had skipped over, but it's very important in SQL queries.